# Webpack - is it possible to minimize package dependency?

Tags: webpack

I'm using a NodeJS package that has 2MB worth of FontAwesome dependencies.

That package exposes a React component, to which you pass an icon type and it returns the a corresponding icon based on the FontAwesome library.

However, after inspecting my source maps, i noticed that 2MB out of the total 2.3MB of my app is coming from node modules (FontAwesome), thanks to that package.

I was just wondering - is there a way to minimize the size? Or every time i import that package i have to include all of its dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

That package itself is controlled by the person or group who maintain it, so if they don't provide a way then you cannot use this package and also minimize it's dependencies.

Npm packages just save you work. If the file size is not worth the work you saved, maybe don't use the package. For instance: say you use this package to display social share icons. This package saves you having to create image elements and inject them into the DOM. If you only needed to do that once, using a package that uses Components to achieve this may be overkill.

Essentially, these would be gradual steps down from what you have now:

- Use font-awesome web fonts package
- Use font-awesome web fonts cdn
- Download font-awesome SVG icons that you want and use them as image elements.

It's just a balance and it's up to you and the needs of your project.